# Parsing Gmail data to spreadsheet creates multiple rows instead of one

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, google-apps-script, gmail-api

Goal: Pull gmail and parse specific data using RegEx and putting that data into a single row

Problem: Instead of the data being added to a single row it's adding to several rows. The getGmail function by itself properly puts everything into a single row but once I run the getGmail function with the extractDetails function it no longer puts the data into a single row. Below is a screenshot of the result of the script in the spreadsheet

```
function onOpen() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const menu = ui.createMenu('Gmail');
  menu.addItem('Get Gmail', 'getGmail')
  menu.addToUi();
}


function getGmail(){
 
 
 
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Billing");
  var threads = label.getThreads();
 
  for (var i = threads.length - 1; i >=0; i--){
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
   
    for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
      var message = messages[j];
      extractDetails(message);
      GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
     
    }
    threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}


function extractDetails(message){
 
  var emailData = {
    date: "Null",
    sender: "Null",
    subject: "Null",
    body: "Null",
    recipient: "Null",
    amount: "Null",
    fee: "Null",
    total: "Null"
  }
 
  var emailKeywords = {
    recipient: "Recipient:*",
    amount: "Amount Sent",
    fee: "Fee",
    total: "Total Amount Charged*"
  }
 
  emailData.date = message.getDate();
  emailData.sender = message.getFrom();
  emailData.subject = message.getSubject();
  emailData.body = message.getPlainBody();
 
  var regExp;
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.recipient + ").*");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
  
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.amount +").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.recipient = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
  regExp = new RegExp("(?<=" + emailKeywords.fee + ").*[0-9]*\.[0-9]+[0-9]+");
  emailData.fee = emailData.body.match(regExp).toString().trim();
 
 
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 
  var emailDataArr = [];
 
  for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
 
 
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
 
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix.

```
for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
 
 
  activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
 
  }
```

Should be

```
for(var propName in emailData){
    emailDataArr.push(emailData[propName]);
 
  }
 activeSheet.appendRow(emailDataArr);
```